# How can I have a single tap to select text in WKWebView

Tags: swift, gesture, wkwebview

I want one single tap to select text instead of long press to select text.

is it a way to do that?

or using `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to wake the long press action?

thanks.

Comment: I would take a look at this

https://gist.github.com/davidortinau/2523148

Comment: I don't really know javascript. how does it work?

Comment: @NiallKiddle I tried the code. it's partially I want. I can get the selected text. but I want a single tap and select the text immediately rather than long press.

Answer (score -1):

```
let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.singleTapAction(_:)))
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)  



func singleTapAction() {
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()

    textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
}
```

Comment: He is trying to select text in a `WKWebView` so there wouldn't be any native `textField` object.